# Three points $x,y,z$ are chosen at random on the point interval $(0,1)$. What is the probability that $x \le y \le z$?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

I have been trying this problem for a while. But, couldn't find any solution. How do I solve this?

Comment: Because the chance of any of them being equal is $0$, we can ignore that. What do you get from all of the possible orderings of the variables being equally likely?

Comment: $3!$ total cases and only one happens so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^z\int_0^ydxdydz=\int_0^1\int_0^zydydz=\int_0^1\frac{z^2}{2}=\frac 1 6$

or... read the comment

You can also choose another of the six possible integration orders:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_x^1\int_x^zdydzdx=\int_0^x\int_x^1(z-x)dzdx=\int_0^1\left[\frac{z^2}2-xz\right]_{z=x}^1dx=\int_0^1\left(\left(\frac 1 2 -x\right)-\left(\frac{x^2}2-x^2\right)\right)dx=\int_0^1\left(\frac 1 2 -x+\frac {x^2}2\right)dx=\left[\frac x 2 - \frac {x^2} 2+\frac{x^3}6\right]_0^1=\frac 1 6$

Comment: Could you please write this integral in other forms as well? like $dydzdx,dzdydx,$